# Assigning a score to a phrase

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python programming, I am trying to assign a score to a phrase or word containing some element without stopwords

I have tried dividing the score but i still get error

```
list = ["information", "james", "goat"]
phrase = ["information is", "James is a boy" ,"goat"]

score = []
for n in phrase:
    score.append(phrase.count(n))


print(phrase)
print(score)
```

I expect the output to be [("information is", 0.1), ("James is a boy", 0.2), ("goat", 0.1)] but i am getting [information is, james is a boy, goat] 
[1,1,1]

Comment: Can you explain why those are the scores you're expecting to see?

Comment: You are looping over each element `n` of `phrase` and then count how many times `n` appears in `phrase`. In your case each element is unique, so you get `[1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: Do you mean the last item in output to be _("goat", 0.3)_ ?

Comment: There is more than one thing wrong with your code, so what is your question?

Comment: I want to score each phrase with the number of words that is in the list contained in the phrase. E.g. if a phrase contains two words from the list, give it a score of 0.2, if it contains only one, give it a score of 0.1, if it contains 3, give it 0.3..... e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists of values and you want to pair them. The answer is the built-in zip function. Try

```
zip(phrase, score)
```

which generates pairs of corresponding elements. (Because it's a generator if you want to see all the values you may wish to use `list(zip(phrase, score))` instead.

You are seeing `1` rather than `0.1` because the list `count` method always returns the integer number of occurrences seen.